Parent Child table with Child table Edit inline option in Angular Material UI
I want to add child table with inline Edit option on Material UI Parent Table/Grid View in Angular Material UI. I have tried several options like the below:
on the "app.component.html"
<table mat-table [dataSource]="parentDataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Parent columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Parent Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let parent"> {{ parent.name }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let parent">
      <button mat-button (click)="parent.isExpanded = !parent.isExpanded">
        {{ parent.isExpanded ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Children
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Parent Row -->
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let parent; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

  <!-- Detail Row for Child Table -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let parent" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
      <div *ngIf="parent.isExpanded">
        <!-- Child Table -->
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="parent.children" class="child-table">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="childName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Child Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let child"> {{ child.name }} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="childAge">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let child"> {{ child.age }} </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let child">
              <button mat-button (click)="editChild(parent, child)">Edit</button>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['childName', 'childAge', 'actions']"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let child; columns: ['childName', 'childAge', 'actions']"></tr>
        </table>

        <!-- Edit Child Form -->
        <div *ngIf="editingChild && selectedParent?.id === parent.id" class="edit-form">
          <h3>Edit Child</h3>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="editingChild.name" placeholder="Name" />
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="editingChild.age" placeholder="Age" type="number" />
          </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-button (click)="saveChild()">Save</button>
          <button mat-button (click)="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="expanded-row"></tr>
</table>


I have added the below code on the "app.comonent.ts"  but it is not working.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Parent, Child } from './models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-child-table',
  templateUrl: './parent-child-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-child-table.component.css']
})
export class ParentChildTableComponent {
  // Sample data
  parents: Parent[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Parent 1', children: [{ id: 1, name: 'Child 1', age: 10 }, { id: 2, name: 'Child 2', age: 12 }] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Parent 2', children: [{ id: 3, name: 'Child 3', age: 8 }] }
  ];

  // Data source for the parent table
  parentDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.parents);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'actions'];

  // Properties to manage child editing
  editingChild: Child | null = null;
  selectedParent: Parent | null = null;

  // Selects a child for editing
  editChild(parent: Parent, child: Child) {
    this.editingChild = { ...child };
    this.selectedParent = parent;
  }

  // Saves the changes to the child
  saveChild() {
    if (this.selectedParent && this.editingChild) {
      const index = this.selectedParent.children.findIndex(c => c.id === this.editingChild?.id);
      if (index >= 0) {
        this.selectedParent.children[index] = this.editingChild;
        this.parentDataSource.data = [...this.parents];
        this.cancelEdit();
      }
    }
  }

  // Cancels the editing mode
  cancelEdit() {
    this.editingChild = null;
    this.selectedParent = null;
  }
}

models.ts
// models.ts

export interface Child {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  // Add other fields as needed
}

export interface Parent {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  children: Child[];
}

Finally I am getting some errors

check this stackblitz try using the same approach

Finally I have made a project on stackblitz and post it. Please check and expecting others solution also
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntgokh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
